# Why would the zoom button not show up in photoswipe?

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I am trying to implement photoswipe in a new website, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why the zoom button won't show up.  I tried in chrome and IE.  I can pinch to zoom in mobile, but that may just be the built in zoom capability of the mobile device.

Everything else seems to be working like a charm.

Comment: I think there's something wrong. Next.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a test picture with a high resolution on your computer (over 1500x1500x)? When my picture is already at 100% width and height no zoom button is shown. When it's under 100% a zoom button is shown.

Comment: OK, I left the image at high resolution, but sent it to photoswipe defined as 800x600.  All it does, is it shrinks it down to 800x600 and does not provide a zoom button

Comment: Can you try use a high res images + set its exact size `data-size="{width}x{height}"`? Or resize your browser window and reload. Does the loupe then appear?